# Seeing folders of linux server in VSCode after switching nodes

Tags: ssh

I'm connecting to a remote host in an entry node and I can see the folders on vscode just fine, but when I switch to the home node using `ssh home` I can't see those folders (nor drag and drop files to upload them to the server like one would do with Moba)

What I have:
[image]

Now, in the terminal, I switch from an entry node to a home node using the ssh command above, but the icons are still of the entry node. How can one update the icons so we an see the home folders?

Sorry if the question seems basic

Thank you